# Are these convex optimization problems equivalent?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Consider the optimization problem
$$ \mathcal{P}_1: \qquad \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} c^\top x \quad \text{sub. to } \ g(x,y_i) \leq 0 \ \ \forall i = 1,2,...,M$$

where $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (scalar valued) is such that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ the map $g(\cdot,y)$ is convex, and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the map $g(x,\cdot)$ is convex as well.

Denote by $x^*$ an optimizer of $\mathcal{P}_1$.

Given the vectors $\{y_1,...,y_M\}$ from $\mathcal{P}_1$, define the set $$\mathcal{F} := \{ (F,f) \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m} \times \mathbb{R} \mid F y_i \leq f \ \ \forall i = 1,...,M \} = \{ (F,f) \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m} \times \mathbb{R} \mid \max_{i \in [1,M]} F y_i \leq f \}.$$

For given $(\bar{F},\bar{f}) \in \mathcal{F}$, consider the optimization problem
$$ \mathcal{P}_2(\bar{F},\bar{f}): \qquad \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n } c^\top x \quad \text{sub. to } \ g(x,y) \leq 0 \ \ \forall y \in \{ z \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid \bar{F} z\leq \bar{f} \}.$$

Denote by $X_{(\bar{F},\bar{f})}^*$ the set of optimizers of $\mathcal{P}_2(\bar{F},\bar{f})$.

Say if given an optimizer $x^*$, there always exists a couple $({F}^*,{f}^*)$ such that $x^* \in X_{({F}^*,{f}^*)}^*$.

Comment. The idea is to exploit the convexity of $g(x,\cdot)$ to claim that we can always consider a worst-case half plane $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid F^* y \leq f^*\}$.

The linear case is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363233/convex-optimization-with-parametric-constraint).

Comment: It seems you are careful not to claim that $g$ is jointly convex in $x$ and $y$. Am I correct in supposing that it is not? I don't know if that affects the answer yet, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: You are right, $g$ is not jointly convex.

Comment: By the way, you might want to consider posting this on the SciComp SE, particularly if you have a computational description of $g$ in mind. There are several of us convex types over there. If you do, make sure to link back to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that the problems are equivalent. I know that
$$g(x,y_i)\leq 0, ~i=1,2,\dots,M \quad\Longrightarrow\quad g(x,y)\leq 0 ~ \forall y\in\mathcal{Y}$$
where $\mathcal{Y}$ is the convex hull of the points $y_i$. This follows from the convexity of $g$ over $y$, and does not require joint convexity. Thus if you replaced your half-plane with $\mathcal{Y}$, you would have equivalence.

But any one of the half-planes described by $\mathcal{F}$ contains $\mathcal{Y}$ and is larger than $\mathcal{Y}$. Thus there are points in the half-plane that could obtain $g(x,y)>0$ in the first model, but not in the second. Thus the second model has a more restrictive constraint set, and would yield a higher objective value.

EDIT: Without a fuller understanding of the *purpose* behind your efforts, it's hard to know what the right approach is. I am assuming that there is a reason why you do not want to solve the problem in the original stated form: that is, with $M$ constraints, one for each point $y_i$.

But suppose you can efficiently describe the convex hull $\mathcal{Y}$ in terms of a set of inequalities $Fy\leq f$, where $F$ is a matrix and $f$ is a vector. Then you could rewrite your constraints:
$$g(x,y) \leq 0 \quad \forall F y \leq y\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\sup_{y:~Fy\leq y} g(x,y) \leq 0$$
For fixed $y$, the $\sup$ is a convex optimization problem in $y$. One thing you can consider is finding the *dual* of this convex subproblem. This dual will be a minimization in some variables $z$. The precise result depends on the exact nature of $g$, but it is quite possible that you will be able to rewrite your original problem as a joint minimization in $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Sure, any half plane in $\mathcal{F}$ is larger, but what prevents us to take the one perpendicular to the cost direction $c$ so that the objective value is the same? I mean I am not clear if this can be always done or not.

Comment: I can't see why that matters. You're still restricting the feasible set significantly. And the cost direction is in $x$, whereas the half-planes are in $y$.

Comment: I now think you are right. So I am wondering about a counterexample.

Comment: What if $F \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$? I am thinking on a cone. I mean that following your convex-hull argument, imposing $g(x,y) \ \forall y \in \mathcal{Y}$ may be equivalent to imposing it for all $y$ in a cone $\{y \mid Fy\leq f\}$?

Comment: That's not a cone unless $f=0$. I'm not seeing how that helps. But looking for a counterexample might be a fruitful exercise to help understand the geometry. What is your ultimate purpose, trying to find a way to simplify the problem?

Comment: If it is possible for you to describe the polytope $\mathcal{Y}$ precisely in the form $Fy\leq f$, then one possibility is to use duality to transform the constraints. When I get to a real keyboard I will explain further.

Comment: OK, I posted the beginnings of an explanation above.

Comment: Thanks for your comments (yes, I meant $f=0$ for the cone) and the search for a counterexample. However, I do not think it is obvious. I mean that, even without the dependence on $y$, having a more restrictive constraint set does not mean getting a worse objective.

Comment: No, it doesn't, but you must concede that it is possible. Your original question asked if the problems are equivalent. Without further conditions added to your problem the answer is no.

Comment: I see your point and I probably agree. However, do you agree that your answer does not prove that the answer is "no"? I mean your answer is "possibly true", but as far as we do not have a counterexample, the question is still open. BTW, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Sure, without a counterexample I haven't proven anything. But you're the one wanting to establish equivalence! Seems to me that we have fairly conclusive evidence that the feasible sets are different. That does not bode well. Again, what is your *purpose* here? A different approach may be worthwhile.

Comment: I do not "necessarily want" to establish, I in fact wrote "Say if [...]" ;-). Also notice that the difference in the feasible sets does not always matter. Consider $\min c^\top x $ sub. to $A x \leq b$ with finite optimal solution. Since at least one optimizer $x^*$ is a vertex, I guess there exists $(F,f) \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that the mentioned LP is "equivalent" to $\min c^\top x$ sub. to $F x \leq f$. I am thinking to the half-space passing through $x^*$ and oriented such that $x^*$ is still optimal in that half space.

Comment: There are no specific purposes in my question. I was just thinking about this half-space idea extended to the case with constraints $g(x,y_i) \leq 0$.

Comment: Your LP example is flawed. The only choice of $(F,f)$ that would work to achieve $x^*$ as an optimal value is $F=c$, $f=c^Tx^*$, or positive scalings of these. But this requires advance knowledge of the solution to the problem, and now the entire hyperplane $c^Tx=c^Tx^*$ is feasible and optimal, which of course is quite unlikely to have been the case in the original problem. In particular many formerly infeasible points are now feasible and optimal; and all information is lost in the simplified model to recover $x^*$. Under no reasonable definition of the term is this equivalent!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8344/discussion-between-michael-grant-and-adam)